# Translate the Mosquitto topic matching function from C to C#

Tags: c#, c

I want to translate the topic matching function from Mosquitto (https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/lib/util_topic.c#L138) from C to C# code.

Right now, I have it like this:

```cs
public static unsafe bool MatchTopic(char *sub, char *topic)
{
    if (!sub || !topic || sub[0] == 0 || topic[0] == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if ((sub[0] == '$' && topic[0] != '$') || (topic[0] == '$' && sub[0] != '$'))
    {
        return true;
    }

    var spos = 0;
    while (sub[0] != 0)
    {
        if (topic[0] == '+' || topic[0] == '#')
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (sub[0] != topic[0] || topic[0] == 0)
        {
            // Check for wildcard matches
            if (sub[0] == '+')
            {
                // Check for bad "+foo" or "a/+foo" subscription
                if (spos > 0 && sub[-1] != '/')
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // Check for bad "foo+" or "foo+/a" subscription
                if (sub[1] != 0 && sub[1] != '/')
                {
                    return false;
                }

                spos++;
                sub++;
                while (topic[0] != 0 && topic[0] != '/')
                {
                    topic++;
                }

                if (topic[0] == 0 && sub[0] == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (sub[0] == '#')
            {
                // Check for bad "foo#" subscription
                if (spos > 0 && sub[-1] != '/')
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // Check for # not the final character of the sub, e.g. "#foo"
                if (sub[1] != 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Check for e.g. foo/bar matching foo/+/#
                if (topic[0] == 0 && spos > 0 && sub[-1] == '+' && sub[0] == '/' && sub[1] == '#')
                {
                    return true;
                }

                // There is no match at this point, but is the sub invalid?
                while (sub[0] != 0)
                {
                    if (sub[0] == '#' && sub[1] != 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    spos++;
                    sub++;
                }

                // Valid input, but no match
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // sub[spos] == topic[tpos]
            if (topic[1] == 0)
            {
                // Check for e.g. foo matching foo/#
                if (sub[1] == '/' && sub[2] == '#' && sub[3] == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            spos++;
            sub++;
            topic++;
            if (sub[0] == 0 && topic[0] == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (topic[0] == 0 && sub[0] == '+' && sub[1] == 0)
            {
                if (spos > 0 && sub[-1] != '/')
                {
                    return false;
                }

                spos++;
                sub++;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ((topic[0] != 0 || sub[0] != 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But, I want to get rid of the `char*` and use `string` instead and also want to check properly for a string ending because `topic[0] == 0` will probably fail with some kind of out of bounds exception.

My idea was to replace e.g. `sub[0]` with `sub[subIndex]` and add the `++` operator on the `subIndex` (where `subIndex` is a `int` variable globally defined in the function), not on `sub`. Meaning, that `sub[1]` would be replaced with `sub[subIndex + 1]` and similar.

Does anyone have some ideas regarding this conversion?

Comment: Don't know how you'd do pointer arithmetic in C# without pointers and 'unsafe' mode.

Comment: `sub[0] == 0` is just a way to check that the string is empty (i.e., in this case, to check that we reached the end of the superstring). Instead of increasing a pointer to the beginning of the string, you should just store the starting index and increase it.

Comment: @dyukha That's what I planned to do. Do you see anything else to change?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: The point is: I don't want to do pointer arithemtic, I want to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now the following code. It seems to work quite good:

https://gist.github.com/SeppPenner/17be9fc44b0605619d4b2eefa7f1f105

I will discuss further issues of this here: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1317.

If you see any bugs, contact me here, please.